# function in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I saw this in a codepen "http://codepen.io/jalabkhan/pen/bgNavG". I am confused about how the foreach loop works. Also what is the value of spark, i and array. I am new to programming so please try to make the answer as simple as possible. Thanks Everyone!!

```js
  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    sparks.forEach(function (spark, i, array) {

      if (spark.opacity <= 0) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        drawSpark(spark);
      }
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
```

Comment: spark is the current element on whip loop counter is, i is the index and array is the whole array sparks here

Comment: Please do basic research before asking. This isn't a tutorial site

Comment: So when the sparks obj is called in the foreach loop, the first value 'spark' is current element, from the multiple new elements in the obj, and 'i' is the index like "spark[0]", and the array is the whole Sparks obj. Did i miss something or am i still wrong.

Comment: And im sorry, i know this is not a tutorial site, but im really confused, and i would like an answer. Thanks for Taking your time to advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

The `forEach` method of an array allows you to loop over its values via a callback function. In other words, each value in the array is passed to the callback function in turn, for processing.

`forEach` automatically forwards three arguments to the callback:

- the value of the array item currently being processed
- the numerical index of the array item currently being processed
- the entire array being iterated over

Comment: Thanks alot mate!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark an answer correct if you deem it the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

forEach iterates threw your array just like a for loop does, but it's more redable since you already have the value in your callback function

in your example:

```
function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    sparks.forEach(function (spark, i, array) { 

/*spark is    your current value in the array (like sparks[i] in a for loop), i is 
you current index and array is sparks*/

      if (spark.opacity <= 0) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        drawSpark(spark);
      }
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
```